# Extract a video channel from a dual channels AVI-file

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I have a vehicle drive recorder with two cameras, front and back. It writes data streams from both cameras simultaneously into a single file. [Here's an example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t5ejsd5o58xcmpa/inf1_180111_215321_I.avi?dl=0) (it's 1 minute video, 100Mb long)

I would like to convert such a file extracting only channel from the front camera and all autdio streams using VLC (and/or other tools) (VLC gives better results in playback than e.g. `mpv`, no frame drops etc). But unfortunately I can't find an option for `transcode` to achieve the goal. Does it exist at all?

Comment: Try uploading your video to a site that doesn't completely butcher it. Then maybe I could test.

Comment: There's a button `Download` in the upper right corner which gives a byte-to-byte copy, I've just checked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ffmpeg, use

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a out.avi
```